# If on this site don't show This?

Tags: php, show

I have a problem showing some piece of code on all pages but one, how can I achieve this?

I have this droplet, that is showing on all pages, but I would like it to be shown on all but the first page. So if u are on the link http://www.some-domain.com/index.php  You wont se this.

```
<h4>Calendar</h4>
<p>[[procal-events?section_id=312]]</p>
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: please paste some code so that we can look at it

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition based on URL like below code, it won't display if URL have index.php :

```
<?php
$homepage = "/index.php";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($homepage != $currentpage) {?>
<h4>Calendar</h4>
<p>[[procal-events?section_id=312]]</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, its not homepage the link is actualy like this: http://www.some-domain.eu/si/domov I tried but it's not working.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; return the URI which was given in order to access this page. as you mentioned URL now in your comment, it will return like si/domov/index.php so you can change the $homepage value to /si/domov/index.php instead of /index.php

Comment: Or if your are using URL rewriting then you should assign a page name for all page then on the bases of that page name you can add a condition.

Comment: Thanks I tried but it won't work. But if I understand this code corectly it will show my droplet on index.php, right? So, if the site (homepage) is index.php show this (my droplet).. I need it everywhere but on index.php. I'm not a coder so Im sorry if I got this wrong ...

Comment: You html droplet won't display on index.php bez condition is if($homepage != $currentpage) and it will display every other page. you can change for display on index.php only like ($homepage == $currentpage).....

Answer (score 0):

I got it, in my case I had to put in an ID of a page so this is what I did.

```
<?php if (PAGE_ID != 123) { ?>
... my code ...
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you

R